# display image in reactjs using local path

Tags: reactjs, image, openlayers

"display image in reactjs using local path"
I can only give a url to fetch the image,either from online or hosting the local image using localhost.How to fetch the image using local path destination instead of the urls.

if (myData["status"] == "Active") {
finalTable += " Status:    ";
}
this is the part where i have to give the local path to fetch the image.
Please help,
Thank you.

```
    const designHtml = (evt, mySource) => {
    document.getElementById('popup-content').style.display = 'none';        
    let viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (myView.getResolution());
    let url = mySource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate,
        viewResolution,
        'EPSG:3857',
        { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json', }
    );

  
    if (url) {
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((json) => {
                var myJSON = json;
                const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
                // console.log(myObj);
                if (myObj.features.length != 0) {
                    document.getElementById('popup-content').style.display = 'block';
                    // var1.style.display ='block'
                    var myData = myObj.features[0].properties;


                    myOverlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                    console.log("myData", myData);
                    var finalTable = "<tr class='row'>Table Row";
                    finalTable += "<table id='myTable' style='border: 1px solid red'>" + "<tbody>" +
                        
                        "<tr><td> Cell Name: </td>" + "<td>" + myData["cell_name"] + "</td> </tr>" +
                        "<tr><td> Muncipal: </td>" + "<td>" + myData["municipio"] + "</td> </tr>" +
                        "<tr><td> Node Name: </td>" + "<td>" + myData["node_name"] + "</td> </tr>" +
                        "<tr><td> Provincia: </td>" + "<td>" + myData["provincia"] + "</td> </tr>" +
                        "<tr><td> Status: </td>" + "<td>" + myData["status"] + "</td> </tr>" 
                       

                   

                    if (myData["status"] == "Active") {
                        
                          finalTable += "<tr><td> Status:</td><td>  <img src ='http://localhost/download.jpg' style ='height: 50px; width:50px'/> </td> </tr>";
                       
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(myData["status"]);
                        finalTable += "<tr><td>  <img src ='https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2017/theoreticala.jpg' style ='height: 50px; width:50px'/> </td></tr>";
                        //finalTable += "<tr><td> <img src=" + 'data:image/png;base64,' + inactiveImageURL + " /></td></tr>";
                    }
                    finalTable += "</tbody> </table> </tr>";
                    document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML += finalTable;
                    myOverlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('popup-content').style.display = 'none';

                }

            });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In reactJS if you want to load local image then you have to use `require()` like below

```
<img src={require('../assets/images/image.png')} style ='height: 50px; width:50px' />
```

Comment: Hello,instead of using the url, i have to use local path destination.The url works fine for me.

Comment: still you have to use require() like you have image.png in assets/images folder of the project then use require('../assets/images/image.png') or any path you want to use

Comment: in the output console(developers option),when i inspect the image its showing src="require('../src/images/Active.png')"  its taking in double quotes and thus image is not displaying.

Comment: Seeing your code you're definitively not using reactJS but pure VanillaJS. For obvious security reason, you cannot (or "must not")  access an image from the file:// protocol from  your webserver, which is, I suppose, on http://localhost .  I suggest you to start a react project on CodeSandbox or wherever to see how a proper configured  project in ReactJS looks like.  It will make your work a lot easier.